# Brother HL-1430 laserprinter keeps giving paper error

Tags: troubleshooting, printer, laser-printer, paper, paper-tray

This problem arose when I had plugged in the charger for my laptop. What I didn't notice was that the cord lay on top of the printer, and when I created a printing job, the paper tray got blocked, and the printer displayed an error. Fair enough, this has happened before; I remove the cord, pull out the stuck paper, remove the drum to check if any paper is stuck inside. All clear. But I still get the error.

I've compared the lights to the [LED comparison chart](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/eu/gb/en/faq/faq/000000/000100/000070/faq000170_016.html?reg=eu&c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl1430_eu&Cat=11), which says the error means either of the following:

**Paper jam**
Clear the paper jam.  If the printer does not start printing, press the control panel button.

**No paper**
Put paper in the printer. Then press the control panel button.

**Misfeed**
Put the paper back in properly, and then press the control panel button. The printer will start printing again.

Windows 7 also reported paper problems.

I can't find any bloody paper in the printer, so I assume that this in fact not the case, unless there's a very crumpled piece of paper hidden somewhere very well, which I consider highly unlikely - besides, I've checked countless times by now. This leads me to wonder what could be triggering this; some mechanism must be flunky after the incident, but I know absolutely nothing about the mechanics of a printer.

Do you have any ideas or experience with this? The printer has served me for seven years, and I'd hate to part with it (and buy a new one).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a very small piece of paper is left in the rollers after the jammed paper is removed. Also, you probably tried this but in case you haven't unplug the printer and plug it back in.

Comment: No dice, but excellent advice regardless.